# Why is there no Unicode starting with 0xC1?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

While studying the Unicode and utf-8 encoding,

I noticed that the 129th Unicode encoded by the utf-8 starts with 0xc2.

I checked the last letter of 0xcf.

No Unicode was 0xc1 encoded as 0xc1.

Why 129th unicode is start at 0xc2 instead of 0xc1?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Unicode code points 128 and 129 are valid characters in the `C0` and ` C1` character sets; there are none missing. I'm also not sure what UTF-8 has to do with your question.

Comment: Although the linked duplicate is addressing the use of 0xC0 and you are asking about 0xC1, the explanation is the same for both. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout for more details.

Comment: The linked duplicate is a different question, with a similar answer, so I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate *question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 starting with 0xc1 would be a Unicode code point in the range 0x40 to 0x7f. 0xc0 would be a Unicode code point in the range 0x00 to 0x3f.

There is an iron rule that every code point is represented in UTF-8 in the shortest possible way. Since all these code points can be stored in a single UTF-8 byte, they are not allowed to be stored using two bytes.

For the same reason you will find that there are no 4-byte codes starting with 0xf0 0x80 to 0xf0 0x8f because they are stored using fewer bytes instead.

Answer (score 5):

The UTF-8 specification, [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) specifically states in the [introduction](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-1):

> The octet values C0, C1, F5 to FF never appear.

The reason for this is that a 1-byte UTF-8 sequence consists of the 8-bit binary pattern `0xxxxxxx` (a zero followed by seven bits) and can represent Unicode code points that fit in seven bits (U+0000 to U+007F).

A 2-byte UTF-8 sequence consists of the 16-bit binary pattern `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` and can represent Unicode code points that fit in eight to eleven bits (U+0080 to U+07FF).

It is not legal in UTF-8 encoding to use more bytes that the minimum required, so while U+007F can be represented in two bytes as `11000001 10111111` (`C1 BF` hex) it is more compact and therefore follows specification as the 1-byte `01111111`.

The first valid two-byte value is the encoding of U+0080, which is `1100010 10000000` (`C2 80` hex), so `C0` and `C1` will never appear.

See section 3 [UTF-8 definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3) in the standard.  The last paragraph states:

> Implementations of the decoding algorithm above MUST protect against
> decoding invalid sequences.  For instance, a naive implementation may
> decode the overlong UTF-8 sequence C0 80 into the character U+0000....

Comment: best explaination so far ... implying tgat the bits are just concstenated to the lowest 7 bits in a 2 bytes utf8 atom